# Replacing a string for another string within a Pandas Series (python)

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I would like to r**eplace specific strings** within a **Pandas Series**:

For example, `energy['Country']` gives me:

```
233                             United States of America
234                         United States Virgin Islands
235                                              Uruguay
236                                           Uzbekistan
237                                              Vanuatu
238                                           Venezuela 
239                                             Viet Nam
240                            Wallis and Futuna Islands
241                                                Yemen
242                                               Zambia
243                                             Zimbabwe
```

However, I would like to replace **'United States of America'** with **'United States'.**

I have tried using:

```
energy = energy['Country'].str.replace("United States of America", "United States")
```

However, this has not worked.

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

Comment: This should work, maybe there are whitespaces in front? Try `energy = energy['Country'].str.strip().str.replace("United States of America", "United States")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it.

`energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace('United States of America', 'United States')`

Your original statement makes the dataframe `energy` equal to the single updated column `Country`. You just needed to add `['Country']` on the left side of the equals sign to ensure that you are only re-assigning the `Country` column.